# difference of curve classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $X$ be a smooth protective variety, or just a smooth Kahler manifold. Is it possible to have two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ in $X$ such that their difference in $H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is a non-trivial torsion class ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. For an example of a Calabi-Yau threefold with such differences of curves, see my paper with Pavanelli http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512182.pdf. I am sure there are much simpler examples, however.

Comment: Thanks Mark, and do these two homology classes have non-trivial GW invariants? I am asking this just for curiosity.

Comment: Yes, they do. This Calabi-Yau is a small resolution of a (2,2,2,2)
complete intersection in ${\bf P}^7$, and the curves in question are exceptional curves for this small resolution. Each such curve contributes $1$ to the Gromov-Witten invariants of its homology class.

Answer (score 3):

This is off the top of my head, but I think that the canonical class of the Enriques surface is a torsion class given by the difference of curves. Every Enriques surface is obtained from a rational elliptic surface by performing log-transforms on two of the elliptic fibers. The class $F_1 + F_2 - F$, where $F_i$ are the transformed fibers and $F$ is a generic fiber, is then 2-torsion.

Answer (score 1):

Every divisor class $D$ on a surface is the difference of two smooth, connected curves. Choose a very ample divisor $A$  and an $n$ so that $D+nA$ is also very ample. Then $(D+nA)-nA=D$ so $D$ is the difference of two curves. They may be chosen smoothly by Bertini's Theorem.

ADDED LATER: They may also be chosen to be connected. The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem shows that hyperplane sections of surfaces are connected.

Comment: It seems to me that  your $S'$ is just the product $Y\times E$. To get multiple fibers you have to make some more complicated construction. 

Comment: Yeah, dunno what I was thinking... I totally just got it backwards.

Comment: In dim>1, an ample divisor is always connected. This follows by Lefschetz theorem.

Comment: what is torsion here!

Comment: This works whether or not $D$ is torsion, for any $(1,1)$-class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Can you describe the torsion 2nd homology class in some Enrique surface as a difference of two curve classes?